# Node.js Connect logger usage

Tags: node.js, logging, connect

I am trying to use node.js connect middleware logger() framework.

```
  app.use(connect.logger("dev"));
```

This code puts a log for each and every request . i want to debug the code and  write it to log file in the format (supported by connect logger , say dev here). This debug statement can be from any module of the code where i need to have access to logger() method and give my  objects as parameter and let logger() write to the logfile/stdout.

But on seeing the code of  logger.js(middleware) , it binds the function of  writing the log data of stream/stdout to res.end object which means it executes only once .

Is there any way to call logger method from anywhere from the code (if by global exports)
and use like.

```
      //test.js module 
      logger("some parameter")
```

Please see the return value of the logger() call in the lib file logger.js

```
  return function logger(req, res, next) {
    req._startTime = new Date;
// immediate
if (immediate) {
  var line = fmt(exports, req, res);
  if (null == line) return;
  stream.write(line + '\n');
// proxy end to output logging
} else {
  var end = res.end;
  res.end = function(chunk, encoding){
    res.end = end;
    res.end(chunk, encoding);
    var line = fmt(exports, req, res);
    if (null == line) return;
    stream.write(line + '\n');
  };
}


next();
```

Currently, i am using console.log() statement to trace.
Team , i highly appreciate if any one could throw light on it.

Answer (score 0):

welcome!

The connect logger doesn't modify console.log or listen for stdout/stderr 
output.

Instead, it automatically outputs its own 'predefined' messages on every 
request.

Try [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) or [log4js-node](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) for custom logs.

In the sencha docs, http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html, they explain how to customize this predefined messages, and how to add your own values to it.

But if you are only looking for a custom log format there are really good modules.

Search ["colors" in the npm page](https://npmjs.org/search?q=colors).